# SpringBoot Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth2

Hola comunidad tengo una duda acerca de la autenticacion con Oauth2.

quisiera hacer unas validaciones antes de generar el token que se envia con esta implementación, mi pregunta es en que momento es recomendable hacerlo asi tambien como modificar la trama de salida que es por defecto, la cual tiene una estructura como la siguientes

```
{
    "access_token": "90xxxxx-0ef8-4980-83a6-47d2c736241b",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "7xxxx-609e-4e9f-ab7a-9e573e0e2193",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

Comment: A qué validaciones te refieres? Te dejo el RFC de Oauth2 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749 para que le eches una mirada por si te sirve da ayuda

Comment: @AndresGardiol Gracias, le echare un vistazo, tengo validaciones de negocio que me servirian mandarlas con esta respuesta que genera el Oauth por ejemplo un par de datos booleanos si estos se cumplen generar el token y asi tambien pasar en la respuesta JSON estos datos.

Comment: Sigo sin tener muy en claro lo de las validaciones en si, más que nada por como está establecido el standard. Te recomiendo que veas este gráfico de la rfc https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.2 que ilustra muy bien el flujo que debe ocurrir para la correcta autorización de terceros. Saludos!